# IDX10638 Error when deploying Blazor server to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, identityserver4, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to deploy my working blazor asp net core app on a production machine (Windows 10) running IIS. The app is configured to use HTTPS with a trusted SSL cert. The app loads ok but when I attempt to login with an existing credentials is throws the following error.
I tried giving the cert permissions, the code is running from the AppPool the app is in proc etc. etc.

```
Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
SpanId: 6f14c17b45cc424d
TraceId: 280c6df87969664eb738b976e2c897af
ParentId: 0000000000000000
RequestId: 80000046-0003-d200-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /connect/token

An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10638: Cannot create the SignatureProvider, 'key.HasPrivateKey' is false, cannot create signatures. Key: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, CryptoProviderFactory cryptoProviderFactory)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, Boolean cacheProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean cacheProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(JwtSecurityToken jwt)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateTokenAsync(Token token)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(Token token)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.CreateAccessTokenAsync(ValidatedTokenRequest request)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync(TokenRequestValidationResult request)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.ProcessAsync(TokenRequestValidationResult request)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.ProcessTokenRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.ProcessAsync(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
```

Comment: This error seems to be caused by not assign a password to allow the private key to be accessed. Can you run it locally or on the test machine? here is the similar error you can use as a reference: [IDX10638](https://benohead.com/blog/2018/05/29/idx10638-cannot-created-the-signatureprovider-key-hasprivatekey-is-false-cannot-create-signatures-key-microsoft-identitymodel-tokens-rsasecuritykey/).

Comment: It can also be that the certificate that holds the signing key does not contain the private key part?